# A verb for "be the most important"

Tags: verbs

Contexts:

> Personalized news recommendation plays a big role in helping users acquire their interested information. It consists of two major steps: recall and ranking, in both of which efficiency *is the most important*.

I'd like to find a verb for *be the most important*. Any suggestion?

Comment: _their interested information_ "sounds" a little odd to me.

Comment: The first question possibly has no answer; the second is off-topic on ELU as a request for general writing advice (but 'the most important' is incorrect; either 'of great importance', 'most important' or 'the most important factor').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Got it, thank you.

Comment: @KillingTime What's your advice?

Comment: @namespace-Pt This site does not offer writing advice and for this reason, such questions are closed. There are other less strict language forums that might be able to help you. Take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) of EL&U and see the [help page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to understand the requirements for a good question. Good luck.

Comment: @fev Okay, thank you anyway.

Comment: *...in both of which efficiency [**pre**] **dominates**.*

Comment: "rules" might work although some might find it a bit informal, depending on context.

Comment: Thank you, I think predominate is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ***predominate***:

> to be the largest in number or the most important ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/predominate))

But I personally would go for a phrase made of two words:
***take precedence***

> to be more important (than something else)
>
> - When it comes to making health care decisions, the patient's preference should *take precedence*. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%2Ftake%20precedence%20over))

So your sentence would be:

> ... in both of which efficiency takes precedence.

It is understood that it takes precedence over all else.

Comment: Awesome, thank you fev

Comment: Predominate does not work in OP's example; it defaults to 'be the major constituent/s'.

Comment: The point of the unsmooth sentence is that efficiency *should* predominate more than that it does predominate. I'd imagine efficiency is *key*.